# Is this translation right?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I'm doing English to Latin translation and wanted to know if anyone could help me address the mistakes of my translation:

> Who is there who would allow the city walls to be destroyed on account of the treachery of a few disloyal men? If our soldiers fight bravely, the city will not fall!

I wrote:

> *Quis est qui patiatur moenias delenda sunt pro insidiam pauci impiorum hominibus? Si nostri milites pugnabunt fortitier, urbs non cadet.*

Comment: not sure why the downvote :(

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I got. His reasoning is okay, but when it is put together, it should be:

> *Quis [ibī est],*<sup>1</sup> *[quī], ob paucōs virōs (hominēs)*<sup>2</sup> *infidelēs, murōs tollī (delērī/conrumpī) patiatur? Si militēs nostrī fortiter pugnant, urbs non succumbed!*

1. Words in brackets are direct translations of words that are best left out.
2. Words in parentheses are words that may also work.

My preference therefore would be:

> *Quis, ob paucōs virōs infidelēs, murōs tollī (conrumpī) patiatur? Si militēs nostrī fortiter pugnant, urbs non succumbet!*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your composition, but the wording of the original made me think that the person setting the composition is fishing for a particular construction at the start:  *Quis (homo) est, qui* ...

Comment: *ecquis* seems to be a suitable alternative to the awkward construction “quis ibī quī ...”

Answer (score 0):

*delenda sunt* means "Those things must be destroyed." (in Direct sp.) After *patior,* 3rdconj, use present passive infinitive ( or acc.+ inf.; or subjunctive) of *deleo.*

"of a few disloyal men," will be a noun and two adjectives, all three in agreement in the Genitive plural.(You have one nominative (or genitive singular), one genitive plural, and one ablative)

Can *pro* mean 'because of'? I would have expected *ob* +Accusative.

*fortitier* is a typo.

The down-vote probably expresses a wariness of interfering between real-world teachers and students.